# How To Set Temporary Or Short Term Form Authentication

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to write a login page using Login tool, which **allows** the user to login.

But for some user, it only allows them to login this webpage for 3 days, after that it will not allow them to login again without giving them new **permissions**.

For this purpose, I want to let program do it **automatically** without Admin to change their **Roles** or Lock their account manually.

Anyone have any idea to do this?

By the way, I am using MySql and ASP.NET C# Framework 4.0

Comment: improved formatting and corrected grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a **table** in the **database** with an **expiration date column**

Example:

```
userId loginUser password expirationDate
```

I put in the logic of login control if expired account.